# SharePoint 2010 change alert email message

Tags: alert, email

Hi is there a way to change the content of the alert email associated with a document library or a list? In SP2007, I know it is possible to do so by changing the alertteamplate.xml in the 12 hive. Did anything change in 2010?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I assume this still works in SharePoint 2010: you should create a modified template file AlertTemplates_edited.xml in ...\14\TEMPLATE\XML (don't modify the original file - make a new version with a new name). You then need to use an stsadm command: stsadm -o updatealerttemplatefiles, and probably do an iisreset and bounce the timer service.

Another way, which may be preferable, is to disable the email alerts and create your own re-usable workflow instead in SharePoint Designer, using the Send Email action. This will give you the opportunity to define the email message format using SharePoint Designer. A bit more effort, but you don't need to touch the files on the server.

Comment: I agree, I've never liked alerts and prefer to use workflows instead.